# Set value of output inside control in repeatable section

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have my own control, which has model with action which is executing when form is loaded:

```
<xf:model>
   <xf:action ... >
       <xf:setvalue ref="???" value="some_value"/> 
   </xf:action>
</xh:model>
```

I put this control to my xforms file to the repeatable section:

```
<section-3>
   <section-3-iteration>
       <my-control/>
       <output-control/>
   </section-3-iteration>
   <section-3-iteration>
       <my-control/>
       <output-control/>
  </section-3-iteration>
</section-3>
```

Now I want to reference to the output control from my control, I mean I want to set output-control value inside control. What should I write to ref attribute in setvalue in my control?

I tried to put there: ref="../output-control", but it doesn't work. When I write: ref="xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')//*[name() = 'output-control']" it set value od output-control only in first iteration.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit dangerous because it violates encapsulation. But if you really need to, try:

```
ref="xxf:binding('my-binding')/../output-control"
```

where `my-binding` refers to your custom control's `id` attribute on `xbl:binding`:

```
<xbl:binding id="my-binding" xxbl:mode="binding" ...>
```

Comment: And one more simple question: what if I have ouptut-control in variable: <xf:var as="xs:string" name="control-name" value="'output-control'"/> ? Now, when I use: ref="xxf:binding('my-binding')/../$control-name" it doesn't work. When I use: ref="xxf:binding('my-binding')/../*[name()=$control-name]" it works but what if I want to refer to attribute: output-control/@some_attribute?

Comment: `xxf:binding('my-binding')/../$control-name"` doesn't work because this doesn't follow the XPath syntax. After a `/` you must have a literal element name, possibly with wildcards for the namespace prefix and/or element name. Using a function also works in some conditions.

For attributes, simply:

`xxf:binding('my-binding')/../*[name()=$control-name]/@some_attribute`

Comment: Ok, bu what if I have attribute name also in variable? I have control name and attribute name in variables: $control-name and $attr-name.

Comment: Then `xxf:binding('my-binding')/../*[name()=$control-name]/@*[name() = $att-name]`